# Custom ADT vs. Tree for parser return value

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I'm using Parsec to build a simple Lisp parser.

What are the (dis)advantages of using a custom ADT for the parser types versus using a standard Tree (i.e. `Data.Tree`)?

After trying both ways, I've come up with a couple points **for** custom ADTs (i.e. `Parser ASTNode`):

- seems to be much clearer and simpler
- others have done it this way(including [Tiger](http://legacy.cs.uu.nl/daan/parsec.html), which is/was bundled with Parsec)

and one **against** (i.e. `Parser (Tree ASTNode)`:

- `Data.Tree` already has Functor, Monad, etc. instances, which will be very helpful for semantic analysis, evaluation, calculating code statistics

---

For example:

1. custom ADT

   ```
   import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec


   data ASTNode 
     = Application ASTNode [ASTNode]
     | Symbol String
     | Number Float
     deriving (Show)


   int :: Parser ASTNode
   int = many1 digit >>= (return . Number . read)


   symbol :: Parser ASTNode
   symbol = many1 (oneOf ['a'..'z']) >>= (return . Symbol)


   whitespace :: Parser String
   whitespace = many1 (oneOf " \t\n\r\f")


   app :: Parser ASTNode
   app =
     char '(' >>
     sepBy1 expr whitespace >>= (\(e:es) ->
     char ')' >>
     (return $ Application e es))


   expr :: Parser ASTNode
   expr =  symbol  <|>  int  <|>  app
   ```

   example use:

   ```
   ghci> parse expr "" "(a 12 (b 13))"
   Right 
     (Application 
       (Symbol "a") 
       [Number 12.0, Application 
                       (Symbol "b") 
                       [Number 13.0]])
   ```
2. `Data.Tree`

   ```
   import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
   import Data.Tree


   data ASTNode 
     = Application (Tree ASTNode)
     | Symbol String
     | Number Float
     deriving (Show)


   int :: Parser (Tree ASTNode)
   int = many1 digit >>= (\x -> return $ Node (Number $ read x) [])


   symbol :: Parser (Tree ASTNode)
   symbol = many1 (oneOf ['a' .. 'z']) >>= (\x -> return $ Node (Symbol x) [])


   whitespace :: Parser String
   whitespace = many1 (oneOf " \t\n\r\f")


   app :: Parser (Tree ASTNode)
   app =
     char '(' >>
     sepBy1 expr whitespace >>= (\(e:es) ->
     char ')' >>
     (return $ Node (Application e) es))


   expr :: Parser (Tree ASTNode)
   expr =  symbol  <|>  int  <|>  app
   ```

   and example use:

   ```
   ghci> parse expr "" "(a 12 (b 13))"
   Right
    (Node
      (Application 
        (Node (Symbol "a") []))
      [Node (Number 12.0) [],
       Node 
         (Application 
           (Node (Symbol "b") []))
         [Node (Number 13.0) []]])
   ```

   *(sorry for the formatting -- hopefully it's clear)*

Comment: I don't quite see what "Tree ASTNode" gets you, given that the sub-tree is being represented as an AST. I'd have thought that what you really have is a Tree of Terminals (strings or numbers), where application is indicated by a node value followed by a sub-list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd absolutely go for the AST, because interpretation/compilation/language analysis in general is very much driven by the **structure** of your language.  The AST will simply and naturally represent and respect that structure, while `Tree` will do neither.

For example, a common form of language implementation technique is to implement some complex features by translation: translate programs that involve those features or constructs into programs in a subset of the a language that does not use them (Lisp macros, for example, are all about this).  If you use an AST, the type system will, for example, often forbid you from producing illegal translations as output.  Whereas a `Tree` type that doesn't understand your program will not help there.

Your AST doesn't look very complicated, so writing utility functions for it should not be hard.  Take this one for example:

```
foldASTNode :: (r -> [r] -> r) -> (String -> r) -> (Float -> r) -> r
foldASTNode app sym num node = 
    case node of
      Application f args -> app (subfold f) (map subfold args)
      Symbol str         -> sym str
      Number n           -> num n
    where subfold = foldASTNode app sym num
```

And in any case, what sort of `Functor` do you wish to have on your AST?  There's no type parameter on it...